# Combine Two JavaScript Functions on same Textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

Hi I have this function:

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    $("#Log_InventoryNo").mask("aa*999999"), { placeholder: " " };
});
```

And this function:

```
$('#Log_InventoryNo').maxlength({
    alwaysShow: true,
    threshold: 10,
    warningClass: "label label-success",
    limitReachedClass: "label label-important",
    separator: ' of ',
    preText: 'You have ',
    postText: ' chars remaining.',
    validate: true
});
```

Problem is that the maxlength function produces unexpected results with the mask function (it works fine on its own) as there a way to get both functions to work perfectley well together? I will add the mask function works fine with the maxlength function. When they are both loaded the maxlength function doesn't work and shows incorrect count for values in the textbox

Answer (score 0):

Looks like these are custom functions . can we see the function definitions? My guess is that they are storing values in the element's $.data() using same variable name.

Comment: they are as they are wrote. They don't have any definitions

Comment: are you suing a plugin? there are no maxLength or mask  functions in jquery without plugins.

Comment: Yes I'm using http://mimo84.github.io/bootstrap-maxlength/ and http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/

Comment: can you create a fiddle (jsfiddle.net) where we may debug your code? otherwise, start by checking  $("#Log_InventoryNo").data() in console before and after executing the functions.